# filter operator explained step by step

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state

```
function deleteTask(id) {
const remainingTasks = tasks.filter((task) => id !== task.id);
setTasks(remainingTasks);
```

}

Ijust want to know in plain english, as if I was a 5 years old, what is going on here, step by step?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp

Answer (score 1):

The [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

Here is what is going on in that code, step by step:

1. `deleteTask` is called with paramter `id`
2. `filter` loops through each element of the `tasks` array, and checks if the condition `id !== task.id` is `true`
3. If the condition is `true`, the element is added to the new array called `remainingTasks`
4. The new array `remainingTasks` is saved to state

See below for an example of the filter() method:

```
const words = ['spray', 'limit', 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'present'];

const result = words.filter(word => word.length > 6);

console.log(result);
// expected output: Array ["exuberant", "destruction", "present"]
```

The `setTasks` function is part of the React `useState` hook. [useState docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

Comment: great,  last question,  what does the [ condition id !== task.id ] really mean?

Comment: @AndreyCarvajal The `deleteTask` function was called with a specific `id` parameter that needs to be deleted from the array. The condition is checking whether the passed parameter is equal to the `id` of each task in the array.  If it is, then that task is not added to the new array (since it needs to be deleted).

Answer (score 0):

The filter function takes in another function as a parameter and returns an array as its result. This function is then run on every element in the specified array (`myArray.filter`). The passed in function should return a boolean value (or something else that evaluates to truthy or falsy). If the returned value for an element is truthy, it will be included in the return array of `filter`. If the returned value for an element is falsy, it will be filtered out, hence the name.

Your code example takes in an id, goes over every task in an array and checks filters out every element with the passed in id.
Afterwards it uses the filtered array to update the state.

Comment: great,  last question,  what does the [ condition id !== task.id ] really mean?